# Expected a value of type 'Map<String, Object>', but got one of type '_JsonMap' in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

after updating Flutter to null safety I got Expected a value of type 'Map<String, Object>', but got one of type ' error.

```
 Future<bool> tryAutoLogin() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     if (!prefs.containsKey('userData')) {
       return false;
     }
    try {
      final extractedUserData =
          json.decode(prefs.getString('userData')as String) as Map<String, Object>;
      print(extractedUserData);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
   
    return true;
  }
```

Does anyone know why it is happening? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you print the return of `prefs.getString('userData')` please?

Comment: can you also include the code of _JsonMap

Comment: prefs.getString('userData') is String? but you try to "as String"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dart, there is a difference between the type `Object` vs the keyword `dynamic`.
What is the difference? Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257735/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-object-in-dart).
Now, if jsonDecode receives a Map then it returns a `Map<String, dynamic>` to allow for calling methods that aren't defined for Object.

Solution: Replace `Map<String, Object`> with `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Also, here is a code style hint: Don't cast a `String?` by using `as String`, use `!` after the nullable value to assume it not being null.

Comment: Man you saved my time, than you a lot